# Overlap test for two digital shapes

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have two shapes that are represented by a binary image and I need to check if they overlap or not. One of them is rotated and translated by known amounts. They can be concave.

[image]

Some inaccuracy is tolerated (about one pixel error) and speed is favored; I am expecting a time complexity linear in the width/height of the bitmaps. Typical sizes extend range up to 512 x 512.

Preprocessing of the shapes is allowed, but only *before* the rotation is applied.

A possible solution I have in mind is to turn the rotated shape into a polygon, use a scan filling algorithm and check for overlapping segments in the horizontal scanlines (the scanline representation of the fixed shape being precomputed).

This would meet the complexity requirement.

Do you see a better/simpler/more efficient approach ?

---

Update:

Without rotation, there is a straightforward solution based on run-length coding of the shapes, with a running time linear in the number of runs. I doubt better can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution that was mentioned in the question could probably be extended to the case of rotated/translated shapes: For each pixel, one has to check whether the *transformed* pixel coincides with a pixel of the other shape.

Assuming that the images are given in some form of 2D-array and the pixels can be accessed (in constant time) with `p = image0[x,y]`. Image 1 is transformed with a 3x3-matrix `M` (which contains a rotation and translation part). Then the pseudocode for the overlap test could be

```
for (each pixel coordinate (x,y) of image1)
{
    // Compute the transformed position of a pixel of image 1
    (x',y') = M*(x,y) 

    // Check whether the transformed coordinate is in the bounds of image 0
    if (image0 contains (x',y'))
    {
        p0 = image0[x',y']
        p1 = image1[x ,y ]
        if (p0 is opaque and p1 is opaqe)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The expensive part will be the transformation of the pixel coordinates, `(x',y') = M*(x,y)`. One could probably restructure this, depending on the target language and data structures, to *first* check whether the source pixel is opaque, and skip this computation for many cases, as in

```
for (each coordinate (x,y) of OPAQUE pixels in image 1)
{
    ...
}
```

But regardless of that, the running time will be *linear* in the number of pixels of one image (preferably, the smaller one).

(If this sounds like a feasible approach, I could try to add a small example implementation (in Java, C-ish style) later today)

Comment: I agree with the "on-the-fly-transformation" principle, but this solution isn't efficient, as it is linear in the number of pixels (like O(N²)). A solution linear in the number of runs is much faster (O(N)). Thanks for the proposal, anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the number of runs"? (I.e. what is a "run" in this case?)

Comment: A run is a sequence of horizontally contiguous pixels. For a convex shape, there is exactly one run per row; for non-pathological concave shapes typically 1-3 per row.

Comment: Well, to some extent I disagree with the "complexities" that you mentioned, but regardless of that: Some more information about the application patterns might be helpful. Did you consider additional data structures, like hierarchies of oriented bounding boxes, spatial hashing or similar ones...?

Comment: That's precisely the goal of my question: finding alternatives. The shapes are hand drawn and have relatively smooth and simple outlines. The given examples are typical, though they can be much larger.

Comment: On the one hand, OBBs could be feasible: They can be constructed once, and then be updated based on the rotation/translation (once I ported some code from http://www.flipcode.com/archives/2D_OBB_Intersection.shtml to Java for this). However, 512x512 is rather small. It is not unlikely that the overhead that is implied by sophisticated data structures (even though they offer a *theoretical* complexity of O(logn)) is large, compared to a simple, brute-force run though some plain arrays. Spatial hashing could be an option, too, but the transformations are comparatively expensive to handle there

Comment: I am already using quick rejection with bounding boxes (taking rotation into account), I should have mentioned that. The next step is to compare the true outlines.

Comment: Sure, the OBBs would then form a *hierarchy*. The highest level would be the bounds as you are currently using them. The next level would be these bounds, split into 4 sub-bounds. (It already warns about "extended discussion in commends", so I'll omit this here, and consider extending the answer (maybe with a few code snippets) later)